# Practically handling many non-stationary forecasting predictors

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, forecasting, prediction, stationarity

This question is about specific strategies to deal with non-stationary variables in forecasting.

This problem usually rears its ugly head when you have a predictor whose levels are relevant to the response, but whose first difference carries very different information. Generally, if there is one or two of these in my model, it suffices to use intercept dummies that are one when the nonstationary levels predictor is 'high'. Similarly, it can sometimes suffice to interact these dummies with various other predictors so I don't have to have the nonstationary variable as a regressor.

But what if I have 15-20 of these nonstationary predictors whose *levels* are all highly relevant to the response? For example, consumer demand being 'high' may be critically relevant to the model; by first differencing I can't incorporate this information into my model anymore. Now consider the case where there are 15-20 other similar variables where the level is critical.

**What is a sophisticated strategy to dealing with this other than using silly amounts of dummy variables, chucking it into a statistical learning algorithm, or chucking them all down the bin?**

Perhaps this problem requires a traditional machine learning solution? Something like random forests make sense, but I am looking to keep the number of parameters down since the speed at which I can get forecasts out of the model is important.

---

To given an example of where levels are important and can't be capture by first differences, look at the following example predictor in `R`:

`plot(sin(1:400/50)+sin(1:400),type='l')`

What's important to my $Y$ is if this predictor is near a peak versus the opposite case of being near a trough. But there is no way to integrate this information into my model by using the first difference of this predictor.

Comment: The inverse of the difference operator applied to a series is the cumulative sum. No information is discarded, the random walk behavior is just detrended out. I can't imagine a scenario where differencing should be avoided.

Comment: @JacobMick It's different. Suppose a non-stationary predictor looks like $X := [0,0,0,0,0,500,500,500,600]$. We may have a data generating process of $Y=X$. But if we were to look at the relationship between $\Delta X$ and $Y$, the last three observations in $X$ would be zero or near zero. Thus the levels are important. The difference tells us whether the predictor is changing. What matters for the predictors in question is whether they're high or low, not whether they're increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @JacobMick look at the example in my post

Comment: I didn't realize that you were dealing with endogenous and exogenous time series. The assumptions for vector autoregression is that all feature time series and the target, requires the same amount of differencing. I'd agree with your post that nonparametric models, taking inputs of both the first difference and the raw would be wise. Perhaps predicting onto delta Y is wise.

Comment: @JacobMick my $Y$ is already stationary in the regression. My DGP $Y=X$ above was just an example to demonstrate what I'm talking about (that you can't just include a first different to get the same information as the levels) and it doesn't reflect the actual $Y$ that I'm working with. Also I'm not working with a VAR. This is just a 1 line equation/regression.

Comment: I think I understand it. Why not include both a difference term and the raw values of your predictors?

Comment: @JacobMick Because the raw values are non-stationary and hence bias the estimates. The crux of my question is **"what's the best way to include the information of these variables into my forecasting model"**? Just chucking them in is one way but I would need to see a justification that the biased parameter estimates are okay for out of sample accuracy in such a situation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a model where the dependent variable is stationary but some of all of the regressors are non-stationary, and you want to keep it that way?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos  I want to be able to incorporate the information of the levels of my non-stationary predictors without necessarily including them directly as regressors, which would lead to a biasing my coefficient estimates. I am asking what is the best way to deal with this - the best way may include throwing them away.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you could look into the concepts and models of "co-integration" and "conditional heteroskedasticity".

In the case where the response appears also non-stationary, then you should look whether it is *co-integrated* with the regressors (you didn't mention co-integration at all in your question). In a nutshell, co-integration exists when the response $y_t$ and the regressors $\mathbf X_t$ are non-stationary, but there exists a co-integrating vector that creates a linear relationship between them that is stationary (or "integrated of order zero")

$$y_t -\mathbf X_t\beta = u_t, \qquad u_t = I(0)$$

If this is the case, a regression in levels can produce reasonable inference and forecasting results.

Another way to approach the possibility of a non-stationary response, is the "conditional heteroskedasticity" approach models. There are too many variants to discuss them here. The essence is that the variance of the process is not constant but depends on the regressors and/or its own past (the "auto-regressive" version).

Let's consider now the case where the response is stationary. Here, before discussing statistical methods, we have to deal with the conceptual problem that arises: *how can it be that a stationary response depends or co-varies with a non-stationary regressor*?

The response being stationary, it has a constant mean, i.e. it has an *attractor* around which its realizations happen. If a regressor is "trend-stationary" (i.e. non-stationary due to the existence of a deterministic time trend), it is difficult to envision that a regressor that continuously rises or falls with each realization, has something to offer in explaining the variation in a process that has constant mean.

Assume now that the regressor is non-stationary in the mean because it exhibits cyclicality (like a trigonometric function). In that case, we could argue that it may influence the seasonality that may be present in the response: this is essentially a way to rationalize the method you described, i.e. turning the quantitative information into qualitative information ("low/high") and use dummy variables. You can increase the level of sophistication here by looking into "seasonally co-integrated" variables and the associated methods.

A final note: it is important to try to determine whether non-stationarity refers to both the mean and (co)variance of a process, or only to its variance, or only to its mean. Each such scenario has different issues to deal with in applied work.